# putting code in seperate file react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this code and it is in my app.js file. But ) want to put it in a separate file, then import it to app.js. I'm using React Native, so how can I do it?

```
 import PopupDialog, { SlideAnimation } from 'react-native-popup-dialog';

 <PopupDialog
   ref={(popupDialog) => { this.popupDialog = popupDialog; }}
   dialogAnimation={slideAnimation}
   width={0.8}
   hieght={0.4}
   dialogStyle={{overflow: 'hidden',borderRadius: 10,}} >

   <View style={{flex:1,alignItems:'center', backgroundColor: this.state.buttonBGColor,overflow: 'hidden',padding:0,}}>
     <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'center' ,}}>
       <Text style={{fontSize:30,color:this.state.buttonColor,fontFamily:'BoutrosMBCDinkum-Medium'}}>
         test
       </Text>
     </View>        
   </View>
 </PopupDialog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can isolate any module into a separate file using ES6 module scheme.

- Popup.js

  ```
  import PopupDialog, { SlideAnimation } from 'react-native-popup-dialog';

  export default class Popup extends React.Component {
   <PopupDialog
     ref={(popupDialog) => { this.popupDialog = popupDialog; }} dialogAnimation={slideAnimation} width={0.8} hieght={0.4}
     dialogStyle={{overflow: 'hidden',borderRadius: 10,}} >
     <View style={{flex:1,alignItems:'center', backgroundColor: this.state.buttonBGColor,overflow: 'hidden',padding:0,}}>
       <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'center' ,}}>
         <Text style={{fontSize:30,color:this.state.buttonColor,fontFamily:'BoutrosMBCDinkum-Medium'}}>test</Text>
       </View>
     </View>
   </PopupDialog>
  }
  ```
- app.js

`import Popup from './Popup';
[Use <Popup /> here]`

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Taha Glad I helped :)